# Enable "Use a default CRS" using Python

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

Is it possible to change the default CRS by code?

[image]

I want to change between "Prompt for CRS" and "Use a default CRS" option by code in QGIS 2.18.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the following to change the setting to use a default CRS:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
crs = 'EPSG:27700' # Change accordingly
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehaviour', 'useGlobal')
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/layerDefaultCrs', crs)
```

Comment: @JoséGabriel - Most welcome, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

or something like this within a plugin:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
my_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(layer.crs().postgisSrid(), QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(my_crs)
```

which changes the project CRS to a desired one (in this example to a CRS from a selected layer)

Answer (score 1):

```
QSettings().setValue('/Projections/defaultBehaviour', 'useGlobal')
```

is changed in QGIS 3.10 and later to

```
QSettings().setValue("/app/projections/unknownCrsBehavior", 'NoAction')
```

possible values: NoAction, UseDefaultCrs, PromptUserForCrs, UseProjectCrs.

Also the **projections\defaultProjectCrs** and **projections\defaultProjectCrs** are changed. The layer default crs is still the same:

```
QSettings().setValue("/app/projections/defaultProjectCrs",'EPSG:2056')
QSettings().setValue("/app/projections/defaultProjectCrs", 'UsePresetCrs')
QSettings().setValue("/Projections/layerDefaultCrs",...
```